# How to use parameters in SQL query with column name

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datacolumn

I have the following SQL query which takes the header from a file and creates a column with the same name as the header:

```
SqlCommand createtable = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " + tbXLSTableName.Text + " (" + dc.ColumnName + " varchar(MAX))", myConnection);
```

It is open for an SQL injection attack so I decided to use parameters like this:

```
string strCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE @TableNameCreateXLS (" + dc.ColumnName + " varchar(MAX))";

SqlCommand createtable = new SqlCommand(strCreateTable, myConnection);      
createtable.Parameters.AddWithValue("TableNameCreateXLS", tbXLSTableName.Text);
```

`dc` is a `DataColumn` object.

I am getting the following error:

`Incorrect syntax near @TableNameCreateXLS`

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: As I said in a comment on your previous (now-deleted) question: "you usually can't parameterize table and column names."

Comment: It was deleted by accident and I lost the page to undelete. So use the old command that I was using?

Comment: Yes. But validate the heck out of the value first - ideally restricting it *really* heavily. (In cases where you want to select from a number of tables, use a whitelist - this doesn't work here, of course.)

Comment: _validate the heck out of the value first_ __:-) :-) :-)__

Comment: *SIGH* that's just not kewl.

Comment: You can  check these names against a list of valid table and column names you can pull from the system tables!

Comment: @JonSkeet, [`SqlCommandBuilder.QuoteIdentifer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.quoteidentifier(v=vs.110).aspx) could help in that, right ?

Comment: @Habib: Possibly - haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use Parameters for Table Name and Column Names, but you can use [`SqlCommandBuilder.QuoteIdentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.quoteidentifier%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to escape their values. Like:

```
SqlCommandBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder();
string columnName = dc.ColumnName;//"somecolumn"
string TableNameCreateXLS = "someTable";
string escapedColumnName = sqlBuilder.QuoteIdentifier(columnName);
string escpaedTableName = sqlBuilder.QuoteIdentifier(TableNameCreateXLS);

string strCreateTable = string.Format("CREATE TABLE {0} ({1} varchar(MAX))",escpaedTableName, escapedColumnName);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot use parameters for table names. I usually see this being done when people want to query a dynamic table, and in those cases I say the safe thing to do is query the table of table names using a parameter, but in your case it doesn't work.

So aside from sanitizing the table name input yourself, I don't think you have any in-SQL way to do this safely. If creating a table dynamically is unavoidable like this, then at least be sure to sanitize the first.

Comment: What would be the best way to sanitize the textbox for the table name. Any SQL method?

Comment: @SiKni8 Admittedly I don't know of a good way to do it manually. The almost universal advice is to use parameterized queries, but here it really doesn't work. At the very least remove ' (apostrophes). Are you sure you want to give the user direct access, with a textbox, to create any table they want?

Comment: Well the good news is the application will be used internally within our group. The bad news is, anyone can be evil at any time ;). I only allow ALPHANUMERIC for the textbox so I should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and see if it works:

```
createtable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableNameCreateXLS", tbXLSTableName.Text);
```